# What's the used format for decimals in the dht11 sensor?

Tags: arduino, decimal, sensors, fixed-point

I am using a dht11 sensor and get the raw bits, where the first 8 Bits are the integral of humidity and following 8 bit the decimals of the humidity. The next 8 Bits are the the integral of temperature, followed by 8 bit decimals of the temperature. In the end there is a 8 bit checksum.

I read some datasheets, but could not find any information about how the decimals have to be read.

Does anyone know if it is a simple fixed-point 8 Bit decimals or do I have to do it differently?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yep, they use the word 'decimal'. It sounds misleading to me, I would say 'fractional' ... Btw it seems that no scale is applied, so you just have to divide your 16 bit value (high-low byte) by 2^8 to get the physical value.

Comment: sry I can not really follow you. I expect the first 8 Bit to be the integral values and the following 8 bit the decimals values. So the number let's say 

2.5 would be 0000 0010 1000 0000

The first 8 bit are the integral, the last 8 one are just simple fixed-point. I do not know why I should divie it by 2^8

Comment: From your example: 0000 0010 1000 0000 = 640 decimal, and 640/256 = 2.5 decimal

Comment: ah sure now I get it thank you really much. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the dht11 datasheet, only positive values for humidity and temperature can be returned, so no bit reserved for the sign.
This is a Q8.8 fixed point representation (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)).
To translate from the representation to the physical value you have to divide by 2^8, where 8 is the number of fractional bits.
So for example:

```
0000 0010 1000 0000 = 640 decimal
640/256 = 2.5 decimal
```